# Is the と here used as a conditional?

Tags: particle-と, quotes

I have the following sentence:

2019年に亡くなったジャニー喜多川氏から若いときに性被害を受けたと、ジャニーズ事務所のタレントだった人たちが言って、問題になっています。

I don't think the と in the first part of the sentence serves as a conditional, but I can't figure out what it is used for. The English translation doesn't help:

> There has been an issue with former Johnny's Office talents saying they were sexually victimised by Mr Janie Kitagawa, who died in 2019, when they were young.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28250/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/15364/9831

Comment: This と cannot be conditional because conditional と never follows the past form of a verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The と is quotative. 「～～と[人]が言う」(「[人]が～～と言う」) means "[person] says (that) ～～."

From [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/28251/9831):

> The 「と」 in 「～～と言った」 must certainly be quotative, right? It is if it directly precedes 「言う」.
>
> When you see or think you are seeing a quotative 「と」 , try putting in imaginary quotation marks the part of the sentence that looks like it is being quoted.

So you have:

> 『2019年に亡くなったジャニー喜多川氏から若いときに性被害を受けた。』**と**、ジャニーズ事務所のタレントだった人たちが**言って**...

The English translation looks good to me.

> ... former Johnny's Office talents **saying** "We were sexually victimised by Mr Janie Kitagawa, who died in 2019, when we were young."
> ↓ ↓
> ... former Johnny's Office talents saying they were sexually victimised by Mr Janie Kitagawa, who died in 2019, when they were young.

Comment: Thanks! That's the first time I see と and 言って being separated like this.